# 405 Not Allowed Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

При авторизации в `wp-config.php` выдает ошибку `405 Not Allowed`
Локальный сервер xampp.
Насколько я понял из "гугла" то это ошибка связанная с недостаточной памятью.
Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно поняли. Ошибка 405 отдается, когда ресурс запрашивается не разрешенным методом (например вы пытаетесь достучатся до ресурса методом PUT, а он ждет только GET,POST или HEAD). Проверьте, правильным ли вы методом стучитесь. Гуф сказал бы, что 405 это как 404, только на один побольше)

Comment: При чем тут собака Микки-Мауса ?

Comment: Я имел ввиду популярного российского рэп исполнителя. Среди прочих своих достижений он прославился гениальной строчкой `Я на седьмом этаже - это как шестой, но на один повыше`. В данном случае сослался на этот известный мем с целью продемонстрировать, что природа 405 ошибки не сильно отличается от всем известной и совсем не страшной даже для обывателя ошибки 404, и никакая ужасная `недостаточная память` тут ни при чем.